# Setting machine-dependent args in launch files?

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any way to set arguments in launch files as a function of machine name/HOSTNAME?

Specifically, I would like to run the same launch file on multiple machines, but with 1 of the args changing based on machine name. I am aware there are (currently) no arg comparators in roslaunch (only if/unless statements), and have investigated the  tag, but was not successful in getting this to work.

Thanks ahead

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230587/setting-machine-dependent-args-in-launch-files?/) by [sr71](https://answers.ros.org/users/25009/sr71/) on ROS Answers with karma: 87 on 2016-03-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can read environment variables from a launch file using `$(env VAR)`. You could use this to read the HOSTNAME variable if that is useful, or you could set a custom environment variable on a per-host basis and use that.

A more complete example would be:

```
<arg name="host" value="$(env HOSTNAME)"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sr71](https://answers.ros.org/users/25009/sr71/) on 2016-03-31**:
Was hoping to avoid that and have everything included in .launch files, but agreed that works.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-03-31**:
There are clever ways to use includes, if you have unique hostnames. For example `<include file="$(find my_package)/hosts/$(arg host).launch"/>`